# Listing items and prices in a output file

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I am making a simple python script to run a budget calculator but when I get to the end, I try to output a text file.

I do all of the calculations just fine, but when I export this to a text file it only outputs the first item.

For example:

INPUT:

5 items, each one 1$, names going up starting from 1.

OUTPUT:

Item: 1

Price: 1

Leftover Money: 0

UPDATED BIT OF CODE:

```
print('You have listed all items, your leftover money is',budget,'dollars!')
for item, price in zip(item_list, price_list):
    file.write(f'\nItem: {item}\nPrice: {price}\n')
file.write("Leftover Money: "+str(budget))
file.close()
quit()
```

I tried looking it up but all I got was different situations with majorly different code. This first started off as a index out of bounds but I managed to fix that but got this instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `for i in item_list` does what you want it to do

Comment: *"my code is always a bit messy so just try to work with it"* - no, please make the code *not messy* before posting it here.

Comment: would it work better with a len(item_list)?

Comment: when you write`for i in item_list` i is the item, not the index.
I would recommend writing `for item in item_list`

Comment: @Oliverbigman `for i in range(len(item_list)):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in item_list` does not return indexes of the items, but the items themselves!

```py
my_list = ["first", "second", "third"]

for item in my_list:
   print(item)
```

Prints

```
first
second
third
```

If you want the indexes themselves, you can use `enumerate`. See the example below...

```py
my_list = ["first", "second", "third"]

for idx, item in enumerate(my_list):
   print(f"{idx} {item}")
   assert item == my_list[idx]
```

Prints

```
0 first
1 second
2 third
```

Comment: Great answer, although `for i in range(len(item_list))` would require no other changes and might be easier to understand for a beginner

Comment: @owninggreendragsdude I appreciate the feedback! This is just my opinion, but `for i in range(len(...))` is pretty un-pythonic, and I would try to avoid suggesting it as an example of what a developer should write. I know as a beginner I would have 100% rather seen examples of best practices than an easier-to-understand variation. Again, I see the need for a tradeoff here, as `enumerate` is not an obvious command. But once you know it exists, you'll reach for it every time.

Comment: @wKavey It works for the for loop, but when I want it to print the items, it only prints the first item and repeats that. How would I get that working?

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code? I'm unsure where exactly you are still hitting issues.

Comment: Got it, so `enumerate(list)` returns two items, `idx` and the item `item`. So your loop should be `for idx, item in enumerate(item_list):`. `idx` is the position, `item` is the same as `item_list[idx]`. Wherever you currently do  `[i]` you will want to replace it with `[idx]`.

Comment: @wKavey it still returns item 1 twice (for 2 items in the list). code: `for idx, item in enumerate(item_list):` then `file.write('Item: '+str(item_list[int(idx)]))`

Comment: You write the first element before the for loop. Then you write it in the loop again. Don't do that. And doing `str(item_list[int(idx)])` is pretty pointless. Not only are you converting the integer `idx` to an integer again and apply `str` to something that is a string, you already have that resulting value in `item`. So `file.write('Item: '+ item)` is all you need (or even better `file.write(f'Item: {item}')`).

Comment: That whole loop could be rewritten as `for item, price in zip(item_list, price_list):` followed by `file.write(f'\nItem: {item}\nPrice: {price}\n')`. Items and their corresponding prices shouldn't be in different data structures anyway.

Comment: @Matthias I ran the python script and put in 5 items, each $1 and it only outputted the first item. Output.txt = `Item: 1
Price: 1
Leftover Money: 0` but it was in the old format for some reason. I will update the code in the question

Comment: `item_list` and `price_list` must have the same length (number of elements).

Comment: @Matthias they should, seeming as I add the item at the same time as the price, just to different lists. Maybe joining them might make more sense? But I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: Ok, it turns out I didn't add the items and prices to the list when I asked for them so it only outputted the one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use index in for of loop you can write

```
str(i)
```

instead of

```
str(item_list[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in item_list` iterates through the items of the list, which happens to hold items of type string (as your error indicates), if you want to iterate through items use:

```
for item in item_list:
    print(item)
    print(type(item))
```

If in addition to iterating through the items, you need to have an index, use:

```
for i, item in enumerate(item_list):
    print(i)
    print(type(i))
    print(item)
    print(type(item))
```